# Expected probability of two seeds becoming apple trees

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

> You have two magical seeds, and you plant both of them on the same day. Everyday, both seeds have a $\frac{1}{3}$ probability of instantaneously fully grown apple trees, and for the other $\frac{2}{3}$ probability, the seeds will remain unchanged.  Find the expected number of days it takes for both of the magical seeds to become apple trees.

I approached this problem with expected probability. Let $E(X)$ be the expected number of days it takes a seed to become a tree. The expected number of days for one seed to become a fully grown apple tree is $E(X)=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}(E(X)+1).$ However, I thought that since the seeds are planted at the same time, the expected probability for both of the seeds to become magical apple trees is the same, and therefore our answer is still $3.$ However, my answer seems a little fishy, and I would like to confirm if I have either done something wrong or if I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that both become trees on the first day is $\frac19$.  The probability that neither does is $\frac49$, so the probability that exactly one does is $\frac49$.  You are correct that the expected number of days for a single seed to become a tree is $3$ days, so $$E=1+\frac49E+\frac49\cdot3\\
\frac59E=\frac{21}9\\
E=4.2$$

Comment: I'm a little confused on why we have to do the $1+$ in front of the $\frac{4}{9}E+\frac{4}{9} \cdot 3.$

Comment: Now I'm getting myself confused.  The $1$ is there because we're only looking at the cases where not both seeds became trees the first day, so the $1$ represents the first day.  Another way too look at it is $E=\frac49(1+E)+\frac59(1+3)$

Comment: Oh okay. I see now. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the last formula I wrote was a bit misleading,  It would be better to write  $E=\frac49(1+E)+\frac49(1+3)+\frac19\cot1$  In fact, now that I look again, the formula in the previous comment is wrong.

Comment: Oh..why the $\cot 1?$

Comment: Because I can't type, or proofread.  It's supposed to say, $E=\frac49(1+E)+\frac49(1+3)+\frac19\cdot1$

Comment: Ah okay. That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not as slick as the official response provided by @saulspatz, but here's another approach. Let $X_1,X_2\sim \text{Geometric}(1/3)$ be iid random variables denoting the number of days for the first and second seed to grow into a tree. You're trying to calculate $\mathbb{E}(M)$ where $M=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$. Let $p_M$ denote the pmf of $M$. Clearly $p_M(1)=\frac{1}{9}$ and, for $m\geq 2$, we have $$p_M(m)=\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}P(X_1=m,X_2=j)+\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}P(X_1=j,X_2=m)+P(X_1=m,X_2=m)$$ This simplifies to $$p_M(m)=\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^m\Bigg[1-\frac{5}{4}\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^m\Bigg]$$ So using geometric series, $$\mathbb{E}(M)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mp_{M}(m)=\frac{21}{5}$$